# Smallest Counter Example Question?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm learning about proving using a smallest counter example but I'm unsure about a specific step our professor did in this example:

$\forall n \geq 0 \\ 1 + 2 + ... + n = \frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$

Base Case: $n = 0$ checks out

By contradiction, we can suppose $\exists x \geq 0$ such that $p(x)$ is False, so
$1 + 2 \ + \ ... + x ≠ \frac{(x)(x+1)}{2}$, and this means that $p(x-1)$ should be True if $p(x)$ is the smallest counter example.

My question is about what we do to prove how $p(x - 1)$ can be in the same form as $p(x)$ such that it creates a contradiction meaning that $p(x)$ is True.

In class, we did

$1 + 2 \ + \ ... + \ x - 1 = \frac{(x - 1)(x - 1 +1)}{2}$ and then decided that we can add $x$ to this to get it to look like what we are trying to prove:

$1 + 2 \ + \ ... + \ x - 1 + x = \frac{(x - 1)(x - 1 +1)}{2} + x$

After simplifying, we can get the right side to look like $\frac{(x)(x +1)}{2}$, meaning that our original claim that $p(x)$ is not True is in fact False. My question is: why are we allowed to do the step where we add $x$ to our step where we have $p(x - 1)$? Aren't we assuming that isn't True? So why are we allowed to use it?

Comment: Well, if $a=b$ then also $a+x=b+x$

Comment: You add $x$ because that's the form that $p(x)$ takes. So you're trying to show that if $p(x-1)$ is true then so must $p(x)$.

Comment: The gist of the proof is to use the well ordering principle. If $p$ is not always true then there is a least $x$ such that $p(x)$ is not true. But in the last step it shows that if $p(x-1)\implies p(x)$ so there can't be a least element. (you need to also consider the case in which $x=1$ separately)

Comment: But aren't we trying to prove that $p(x)$ is true? I am confused about how we're able to use it in our argument when we are trying to prove it.

Comment: @breastshoemann: Exactly where in the argument do you think that you are using the truth of $p(x)$ to prove that $p(x)$ is true?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is essentially, why should this be done as a proof by contradiction?  After all, if we've shown that $\varphi(0)$ is true, and that $\forall{x\in \mathbb{N}}:\varphi(x)\rightarrow \varphi(x+1)$, aren't we done?

Yes, you're done.  Those two facts together imply that $\forall{x\in\mathbb{N}}:\varphi(x)$ (this is the axiom of induction).

But it's logically equivalent to show the contrapositive of the second fact, which is $\forall{x\in\mathbb{N}}:\neg \varphi(x+1)\rightarrow \neg \varphi(x)$, and in some cases this may make for a clearer argument.